# jQuery image slider, define href per image

Tags: jquery, slider, image, href

I have added a specific slider per request to www.edietty.com but it does not come with a variable to assign href per image.  My first though was to try and on-click to direct to an exact URL but any time I attempt to add the href it causes the slider not to display.  I attempted to design through $('#main_image').attr('src','image1.jpg') but when the whole slider stopped displaying I decided to break down and ask for assistance.

The slider is from John Polacek
http://johnpolacek.github.com/ResponsiveThumbnailGallery/

The html is:

```
<article><div id="gallery"></div></article>
```

The JQuery is:

```
(function($) {

    $.ThumbnailGallery = function(el, options) {

        var isUnderBreakpoint,
            currImageNumber,
            imagesPath,
            imageWidth,
            imageHeight,
            thumbWidth,
            thumbHeight,
            gallery,
            view,
            mainImage,
            nav,
            thumbnails,
            buttons;

        var defaults = {
            thumbImages: 'img/thumbs/thumb',
            smallImages: 'img/small/image',
            largeImages: 'img/large/image',
            count: 5,
            thumbImageType: 'jpg',
            breakpoint: 600,
            imageType: 'jpg',
            shadowStrength: 1
        }

        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {}

        var init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            this.el = el;

            gallery = $(el).empty();

            view = $('<div id="gallery-view"></div>');
            view.css('margin','0 auto -1px');

            nav = $('<div id="gallery-nav"></div>');
            nav
                .css('margin','0 auto')
                .css('position','relative')
                .css('background-color','#222');

            thumbnails = $('<div id="nav-thumbnails"></div>');
            buttons = $('<div id="nav-buttons"></div>');
            buttons
                .css('position','absolute')
                .css('top','0');

            gallery.append(view, nav);
            nav.append(thumbnails, buttons);

            isUnderBreakpoint = $(window).width() < plugin.settings.breakpoint;
            imagesPath = isUnderBreakpoint ?
                plugin.settings.smallImages : plugin.settings.largeImages;

            updateMainImage(1);

            for (var i=0; i<plugin.settings.count; i++) {

                var button = $('<a href="#" class="gallery-button"></a>');
                button
                    .css('display','block')
                    .css('float','left');

                var thumbImage = $('<img class="thumbnail-image" src="'+(plugin.settings.thumbImages)+(i+1)+'.'+plugin.settings.thumbImageType+'" />');
                thumbImage
                    .css('display','block')
                    .css('float','left');

                if (i===0) {
                    thumbImage.load(function() {
                        thumbWidth = this.width;
                        thumbHeight = this.height;
                        $('.gallery-button')
                            .css('width',this.width)
                            .css('height',this.height);
                        nav.css('height',thumbHeight);
                        thumbnails.css('height',thumbHeight);
                        updateSize();
                    });
                } else {
                    button
                        .css('box-shadow','0px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,'+ plugin.settings.shadowStrength +') inset')
                        .css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,'+ plugin.settings.shadowStrength/2 +')');
                }

                thumbnails.append(thumbImage);
                buttons.append(button);
            }           

            buttons.delegate('.gallery-button', 'click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.gallery-button')
                    .css('box-shadow','0px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,'+ plugin.settings.shadowStrength +') inset')
                    .css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,'+ plugin.settings.shadowStrength/2 +')');
                $(this)
                    .css('box-shadow','none')
                    .css('background','none');

                updateMainImage($(this).index()+1);
            });

            $(window).resize(function(e) {

                updateSize();
            });
        }

        function updateMainImage(imageNumber) {
            currImageNumber = imageNumber;
            mainImage = $('<img src="'+imagesPath+imageNumber+'.'+plugin.settings.imageType+'" id="main-image" />');
            mainImage.load(function() {
                view.empty().append(mainImage);
                updateSize();
            });
            $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
                .attr("src", $(mainImage).attr("src"))
                .load(function() {
                    imageWidth = this.width;
                    imageHeight = this.height;
                });

        }

        function updateSize() {
            if (thumbWidth && imageWidth) {
                var galleryWidth = gallery.width();

                // check breakpoint
                if (isUnderBreakpoint != $(window).width() < plugin.settings.breakpoint) {
                    // update main image
                    isUnderBreakpoint = $(window).width() < plugin.settings.breakpoint;
                    imagesPath = isUnderBreakpoint ?
                        plugin.settings.smallImages : plugin.settings.largeImages;
                    updateMainImage(currImageNumber);
                }

                // set main image size
                if (galleryWidth < imageWidth) {
                    mainImage
                        .css('width', galleryWidth)
                        .css('height','');
                } else {
                    galleryWidth = imageWidth;
                    mainImage
                        .css('width',imageWidth)
                        .css('height','');
                }

                // calculate number of rows
                var numThumbs = plugin.settings.count;
                var thumbSize = galleryWidth / numThumbs;
                var numRows = 1;
                var thumbScale = thumbSize / thumbWidth;
                var imageScale = galleryWidth / imageWidth;

                // if thumb is below scale threshold, add new row
                while (thumbScale < .5) {
                    numRows++;
                    thumbSize = (galleryWidth * numRows) / numThumbs;
                    thumbScale = thumbSize / thumbWidth;
                }

                // set thumbnail sizes
                var thumbsRemainder = numThumbs;        // tracks thumbs left to scale
                var thumbIndex = 0;                   // tracks thumb index to be scaled
                for (var i=0; i<numRows; i++) {

                    var numThumbsInRow = Math.ceil(thumbsRemainder / (numRows-i));
                    // scale thumbs in row
                    for (var j=0; j<numThumbsInRow; j++) {
                        thumbScale = (galleryWidth / numThumbsInRow) / thumbWidth;
                        var newWidth = thumbWidth * thumbScale;
                        var newHeight = thumbHeight * thumbScale;
                        $('.thumbnail-image:eq('+thumbIndex+')')
                            .css('width',newWidth)
                            .css('height',newHeight);
                        $('.thumbnail-image:eq('+thumbIndex+') img')
                            .css('width',newWidth)
                            .css('height',newHeight);
                        $('.gallery-button:eq('+thumbIndex+')')
                            .css('width',newWidth)
                            .css('height',newHeight);
                        $('.gallery-button:eq('+thumbIndex+') img')
                            .css('width',newWidth)
                            .css('height',newHeight);
                        thumbIndex++;
                    }
                    thumbsRemainder -= numThumbsInRow;
                }

            }

            // update view size
            view.width(galleryWidth);
            view.height(mainImage.height());

            // update nav size
            nav.width(galleryWidth);
            nav.height(thumbHeight * thumbScale * numRows);            
        }

        init();

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin uses the `thumbImages`, `smallImages` and `largeImages` paths, with a number from `1` to `count` and the `imageType` or `thumbImageType` appended. Using your settings, you'd end up with thumb paths of:

```
img/thumbs/thumb + count + .jpg:

img/thumbs/thumb1.jpg
img/thumbs/thumb2.jpg
img/thumbs/thumb3.jpg
img/thumbs/thumb4.jpg
img/thumbs/thumb5.jpg
```

and corresponding small or large image paths:

```
img/small/image1.jpg
img/large/image1.jpg
```

If you don't wish to have your thumbnail and image paths follow a similar setup, you may be better served by a plugin that works differently.